# UploadFile1.PostedFile.FileName is giving null exception error. How to handle this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am developing a website, in which i have to upload excel file. I have a form which is placed inside an UpdatePanel. When i use this code:

```
protected void uploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string extension = Path.GetExtension(Uploader.PostedFile.FileName);

}
```

From the above line..I am checking the extension of the file. If it would be other than .xlsx , i will prompt user that such type of file is not allowed. But the problem is that

Uploader.PostedFile.Name is  giving null error exeception.  This is error message:

NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Kindly help me how to handle this situation. Regards

Comment: Are you using ajax? If you r uploader is sitting in ajax panel you will get null

Comment: Yes as i mentioned. i have placed my form inside UpdatePanel. So definitely im using ajax. But couldnt find any solution yet?
And yeah its getting null...

Comment: As mentioned above you can't use a FileUpload in an UpdatePanel - you will need to initiate a full Postback (this may help http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/fileupload-control-in-update-panel-using-Asp-Net-ajax/)

Comment: @KasimSiddiqui Please vote on answers, do not leave it blank so others can benefit from it

Comment: But nuthing solved my problem yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, because you are using uploader inside UpdatePanel it won't work. There are two things you can do:

1. Use full postback for uploader by utilizing UpdatePanel Triggers, more info here http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers
2. Use Async Uploader from ajax toolkit http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx